# Sanitize project to protect your privacy in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sanitization, privacy

Is there any standard way to protect your privacy in Visual Studio? I find it extremely disconcerting that it creates all sorts of binary files that have my user name and system paths embedded in them every single time I open a project. I'm trying to make a portfolio with some sample code for potential employers, and every time I make a small modification I have to reinspect every file for fear that another with hidden references to my system directory structure and private username has slipped through. (Could lead to an employer being able to more easily locate my facebook, etc., see dumb questions I've asked online in the past.)

It is frightening that even the .exe if complied in Debug mode has references to so much of my personal data. Is there a tool or standard way to handle all of this? Surely companies have to sanitize before releasing projects to the public.

Comment: To be clear: I'm also asking how to clean a PROJECT when you are going to share source publicly.

Answer (score 2):

Independently from your question - a very strong suggestion is to use a version control system like e.g. Subversion. And if you do, you control which files are checked in and which aren't, and binaries usually don't go to source control. I don't check .vcproj.user in either.

So if you want to pass a project to someone else, you can either give him access to the repository or you can do a "svn export" which gives you all versioned files in a new and clean directory. This is the way I would choose in your case.